# stream a .caf audio file from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audio-recording, avplayer

I am working on a project in which I am recording voice and uploading it to the server. The Uploaded file format is .caf (Core Audio Format)

Now, when I try to play this file **from server** using `AVPLayer` then it is giving error message below.

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x2f31e0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action}`

I have checked the file on the server and it is not corrupted.

My question is: can .caf file support streaming ? if not then in which format I need to convert my recorded file that support streaming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this setting in `AVAudioSession`

use .mp4 for play audio both side:

```
     AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
                [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];
                [audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];

                NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
                [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
                [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

                NSURL *recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourdirectorypath];
                //file=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",recordedTmpFile];
                NSLog(@" filr url%@",recordedTmpFile);
               // NSLog(@" filr url%@",file);
                recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];
                [recorder setDelegate:self];
                [recorder prepareToRecord];
                [recorder record];

 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```